# the intersection of n disks/circles

Tags: geometry

Given that $n$ disks/circles share a common area, meaning that every two of them intersect or overlap one another, and we know their coordinates $（x_{1},y_{1},r_{1})$, $(x_{2},y_{2},r_{2})$, ..., $(x_{n},y_{n},r_{n})$, where $x_{i}$,$y_{i}$,$r_{i}$ represent the $x$ axis coordinate, the $y$ axis coordinate, and the radius of the $i$-th disk/circle, respectively, can you provide a method to calculate the coordinate of the centroid of the intersection of these disks/circles?

Comment: I assume you mean that $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the coordinates of the *centre* of the $i$th circle, but you should say so explicitly.

Comment: Can more than two disks intersect at the same point? If so, this looks like a messy calculation involving integrals, and inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @Chris Eagle, You perfer to the explicit descripition. Great! But sometimes implicit descripition is enough. ^^ I guess you are a person who like to pursue perfection.

Comment: @ronno, n disks can intersect at the same point. But you can do not consider this particular scenario.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the area and centroid of the intersection of two disks?

Comment: @ronno, I am looking for the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The intersection of $n$ disks is a convex shape bounded by circular arcs that meet at vertices where two or more circles intersect.

[image]

The first thing to do is to identify these vertices and the arcs that connect them to each other. If no three circles are coincident,$^1$ then this isn't very hard: Consider every pair of circles; find their two intersection points, which form two candidate vertices; if a candidate vertex is inside all other circles, then it is indeed a vertex of the intersection. This gives you a set of vertices.$^2$ Each vertex lies on exactly two circles; using this connectivity, you can sort them in consistent order around the intersection shape.

Now you can decompose the intersection shape into a number of pieces: (i) the polygon (shaded blue above) that connects the vertices, and (ii) a collection of circular segments (shaded red), one for each arc of the shape. You can find the areas and centroids of each piece using closed-form formulas ([polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid), [circular segment](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html)). The centroid of the full shape is then just the weighted average of the centroids of each of the pieces, weighted by area.

---

$^1$If multiple circles are coincident on a vertex, then doing pairwise tests may not always get you a consistent set of vertices, especially if you're using floating-point arithmetic. You might be able to get around this to some extent by fudging the inside-circle test with some epsilon bias, but a truly robust solution would have to come from a computational geometry expert.

$^2$It's possible that the set of vertices turns out to be empty. Then there are two possibilities: either the intersection is equal to one of the circles, or the intersection is empty. It is easy to distinguish between these two cases by checking if there exists a circle that is entirely inside all the others.

Comment: @Rahual Narain, rigorous, thorough, beautiful, you present such a solution. Seem to omit nothing. Very enjoyable.

Comment: @Rahual Narain, how do you draw this graph? What graphic software do you use? It seems that you implement it by coding a program, right?

Comment: @York, if you are happy with this answer, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the grey check mark to its left.

Comment: I drew the figure in [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).

Comment: @Rahual, inkscape, an open source tool, fantastic! Thank you very much.