# Find whether $n$ circles are overlapping over a common area

Tags: geometry, circles, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry

I am provided with the radii and coordinates of the centers of $n$ circles. I want know whether all circle have common area. I don't need to calculate the area.

First, I think if all circles intersect each other, they have common area.But it's wrong.

After searching for a period of time, I found a method is iterative and calculate the area at the same time.So is there any other way to find whether $n$ circles are overlapping over a common area quickly?

Comment: I wonder what is your iterative method.

Comment: This similar question: [common overlap of n circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045766/common-overlap-of-n-circles) has several answers with proposed algorithms. Exert a critical mind, though: there is no proof provided of the correctness of the algorithms, and I think some of them are not correct (in the sense that they would return the wrong result on some test cases)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605826/check-whether-n-disks-intersect

Comment: I would just add - for each pair of centers, the distance between them needs to be smaller than the sum of radii.

Comment: @Moti : you give a necessary condition, not a sufficient one.

Comment: @Jean It needs to be true for every pair - you may improve it with some additional tests. I did not see this basic condition in the reference - but I may missed it.

Comment: @Moti imagine you have 3 circles with radius 0.51 centered in the vertices of an equilateral triangle with sidelength 1 : each pair of circles has an overlap zone but the 3 circles don't have a common overlap zone...

Comment: @Jean You are right! This is a necessary condition.